# Call method with templated parameter

Tags: c#, oop, templates, xamarin

I've got a generic method :

```
protected override void Work<T>(T requestResult)
{
    ...
    CallsSomeOtherMethodFromOtherClass(requestResult);
}
```

But Xamarin wont let me do this.
It says that it can't casts **requestResult** to string (*CallsSomeOtherMethodFromOtherClass* takes a string as parameter).

But in this particular override I am sure that the type T will be a string.

What should I change for the compiler to let me call the method:

```
CallsSomeOtherMethodFromOtherClass(string);
```

Comment: If you are sure that T is always a string, why is the method defined as a generic method? The compiler doesn't know that T is always a string.

Comment: @mm8 In this particular override I know that its gonna be a string. But in  some other overrides It wont be !

Comment: Well, then you need to try to cast requestResult to a string at *runtime*. As far as the compiler is concerned requestResult might be any type T.

Comment: @mm8 I tried ! ->  work((string) requestResult);   But it says that it cannot convert T to string

Comment: At compile time or at runtime? Did you see my code sample...? Maybe you should try it out.

Comment: @mm8 wait ! Did not tried the way you explained in your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Please note this code was written without an IDE and hasn't been compiled. Don't copy and paste it.

What you could do is add a constraint to the generic. So T inherits from X.
In this case T must inherit from interface IWorkUnit.

```
protected override void Work<T>(T requestResult) where T : IWorkUnit
{
    DoWork(requestResult);
}
```

Then DoWork accepts IWorkUnit as a parameter. IWorkUnit will have any properties you may want.

Full example:

```
protected override void Work<T>(T requestResult) where T : IWorkUnit
{
    switch(requestResult.TypeOfWork) {
        default:
        case EWorkType.Test:
            DoTestWork(requestResult);
        break;

        case EWorkType.Work:
            DoWork(requestResult);
        break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could just use pattern matching. I'd suggest to add an enum to IWorkUnit, which shows what type of work the work unit is for.
Then make a factory to determine what method should be used to deal with the request, like so:

```
protected override void Work<T>(T requestResult)
{
    switch(requestResult) {
        case ITestUnit testUnit:
            DoTestWork(testUnit);
        break;

        case string workStr:
            DoWork(workStr);
        break;

        default:
            //Show error
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. The doWork() prototype will have to be changed to accept the type IWorkUnit ? No ?

Comment: It would, but IWorkUnit was just an example. You could use the last example instead if you'd prefer to keep the method's signature intact.

Comment: I'm having a hard time to understand your case instructions. What would be the value of workStr ?

Comment: workStr would be requestResult casted to a string. That case will only be executed if requestResult can be casted to a string :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `Work` is defined as a generic method, there is no way for the compiler to know that `requestResult` will always be a `string`. It might be any type `T`.

If you are "sure that the type `T` will be a `string`", you might as well define the method as a non-generic `void Work(string requestResult)`. It makes no sense to define a generic method that only accepts `strings` anyway.

If that's not possible for some reason, you can try to cast `requestResult` to a `string` at runtime as suggested by @Fildor. This is how you could do this in earlier (C#6-) versions of C# and Visual Studio:

```
protected override void Work<T>(T requestResult)
{
    string s = requestResult as string;
    if (s != null)
    {
        CallsSomeOtherMethodFromOtherClass(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: The work(...) method takes a string in this particular overrides. But in other specific implementation it will be other types.

Comment: Then you are left of casting as I explained in my answer.

Comment: Yes. The compiler doesn't like the conversion: "impossible conversion from T to string"

Comment: And what version of Visual Studio...? This clearly works for me.

Comment: Please provide all code needed for anyone else to be able to reproduce your issue from scratch then.